# useEffect inside child component, running uneccessarily, every time component is called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component and a child component. I'm using `array.map()` method to call the child component for every value in the messages array.

now I want to do something inside the child component every time a button in the parent is clicked. so I've set up a `useEffect` with a dep array, inside the child.

Is this the right approach?
because if there are 100 values inside the array the useEffect will be called those many times.
and if I'm doing something heavy such as using a for loop inside the effect, won't it be a bad implementation?

Is there a better approach for this scenario? especially when I only want to run the useEffect for a few selected array values?

parent component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function App() {

  let [clicked,setClicked] = useState(false);
  let messages = ['a','n','c','d'];
  

  let changer = () =>{
    setClicked(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {messages.map((o) => (
                                            
        <div>
          <Childcomp clicked={clicked}/>
        </div>
        
       ))}
       <button onClick={changer}> click me </button>
    </div>
  );


}
```

child component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export function Child({clicked}) {

  useEffect(()=>{

    if(clicked){
      console.log('parent tapped :)');   // do something useful/heavy

    }

  },[clicked])

 
  return (
    <div className='child'>
       <p className='class1'>hi i'm child</p>
    </div>
  );


}
```

Comment: "The right approach" for what?  If the goal is that every child component executes that operation when the button is clicked in the parent, then wouldn't you want every child component to execute that operation when the button is clicked in the parent?  Isn't that what currently happens?  So, isn't that the intended result?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.  If you want to execute this only for a *specific* child component (or subset of child components) then you'd need to differentiate them in some way.  How do you know which child component(s) should execute the operation?

Comment: i would gather them up in a special array. so, the idea behind what you say is to run the effect conditionally. like if a certain message is included in both the arrays only then execute what is inside the effect? alright i'm not executing, what is inside useEffect for every array value (those not in the special array), but the useffect is still called (initial render), is this unecessary call for useEffect alright? (implementation wise)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do that?  Where in the code shown do you "gather them up in an array" and where do you perform the conditional logic to execute or not execute the operation in the child component?

Comment: the gathering process is a series of steps and showing the entire code here would only serve to wasting time. all that would be irrelevant to my actual question. all i'm asking is, whether calling useEffect so many times alright? (even if doesnt perform any useful thing, in case of those values that aren't present in the special array)

Comment: If you're just looking for a review and feedback on otherwise working code then you're probably looking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if component will render for first item of array then `useEffect` will called. for the other items of array `useEffect` will return and will not do anything.

```
// App.jsx

import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function App() {

  let [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  let messages = ['a', 'n', 'c', 'd'];

  let changer = () => {
    setClicked(!clicked);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {messages.map((o, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <Child clicked={clicked} index={index} />
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={changer}> click me </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// Child.jsx
export function Child({ clicked, index }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (index !== 0) return;
    console.log('parent tapped :)'); 
  }, [clicked, index]);

  return (
    <div className='child'>
      <p className='class1'>hi i am child</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if there are a 100 values inside the array the useEffect will be called those many times.

You are right, with your implementation when `clicked` state change value in the parent component, `useEffect` of each returned `Childcomp` will fire since `clicked` props is included in the dependecy array

It seems like you want to run `useEffect` only for one specific `Childcomp` but which one? it is not clear with your implementation, since here `clicked` state is a simple boolean value.
If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you might need to store the index of the clicked `Childcomp` in  `clicked` state because otherwise, you'll have no information about which child component should run its `useEffect` hook:

```js
export function App() {

  let [clicked,setClicked] = useState();
  let messages = ['a','n','c','d'];
  

  let changer = (index) =>{
    setClicked(index);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {messages.map((o, index) => (
                                            
        <div key={index} onClick={() => {changer(index)}}>  
          <Childcomp clicked={clicked} index={index}/> 
        </div>
        
       ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now with this update, each time you click the wrapper `div` of one `Childcomp` you store its `index` in `clicked` state.

**Note:** if it is possible, better to store `o.id` and use it as `index`.
 I kow thet `o` is a string here but maybe this is a simple example.

```html
<div key={o.id} onClick={() => {changer(o.id)}}> 
    <Childcomp clicked={clicked} index={o.id}/> 
</div>
```

In the child component, you still need to fire `useEffect` each time `clicked` props changes, you can't avoid that,  but you can make the code inside the effect run only when the clicked child component is that one, i.e. when `index` props is equal to `clicked` props

```js
export function Child({clicked, index}) {

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('useEffect is running')
    if(clicked === index ){ 
      console.log(`the code inside the effect is running only for the component with the index equal to ${index} `); 
    // do something useful/heavy
    }
  },[clicked])

  return (
    <div className='child'>
       <p className='class1'>hi i'm child</p>
    </div>
  );

}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-fire-f6plqx?file=/src/App.js)